# Codeigniter Query Builder join table with LIKE condition instead of where?

Tags: codeigniter-3, query-builder

I can't find any answer in the documentation, I'm trying to achieve this:

$this-db->join("table", "column LIKE %string%");

But it's not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->join('table', 'table.a = table2.b');

$this->db->like('field_name_in_table','value_to_be_compared');
```

try this.
**Note:** Here table2 is base table.